# Get length of Azure queue from Python via REST API

Tags: python, rest, azure

Has anyone got an example of this?

This page describes the REST API function I'm trying to use:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/get-queue-metadata

This page describes the authorization process. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to specify how to form the authorization string that would be suitable for the above API function:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/authentication-for-the-azure-storage-services

Here's what I've tried. I get a 403 "Forbidden" response code:

```
import base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac, requests

account_name = 'account123'
account_key = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789abcdefghijklmn=='
queue_name = 'stuff-to-process'

resource = '/{}/{}?comp=metadata'.format(account_name, queue_name)
rfc1123date = datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S GMT')
x_headers = 'x-ms-date:' + rfc1123date
string_to_hash = 'GET\n\n\n\n' + x_headers + '\n' + resource
bytes_to_hash = bytes(string_to_hash).encode('utf-8')
decoded_key = base64.b64decode(account_key)
encoded_hash = base64.b64encode(hmac.new(decoded_key, bytes_to_hash, digestmod=hashlib.sha256).digest())

url = 'https://{}.queue.core.windows.net/{}'.format(account_name, queue_name)
headers = {
    'Authorization': 'SharedKeyLite ' + account_name + ':' + encoded_hash,
    'x-ms-date': rfc1123date
}

response = requests.get(url, params={'comp':'metadata'}, headers=headers, timeout=5)
print 'Response code was', response.status_code
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to reproduce the issue, and the error response below has shown the reason via `print response.text`.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code>
>   <Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization h
> eader is formed correctly including the signature.
> RequestId:927f38e8-0003-0023-76ad-c84979000000
> Time:2017-05-09T10:14:33.8632801Z</Message>
>   <AuthenticationErrorDetail>Authentication scheme SharedKeyLite is not supported.</AuthenticationErrorDetail>
> </Error>
> ```

The key is `Authentication scheme SharedKeyLite is not supported.` So please use `SharedKey` instead of `SharedKeyLite` in the request header `Authorization` of your code, then it works and you can extract the queue length value from the responce header `x-ms-approximate-messages-count` via `response.header["x-ms-approximate-messages-count"]`

Comment: Very useful info Peter. Many thanks. I will try what you say. But, the authentication docs I linked to say, "You may use Shared Key Lite authentication to authenticate a request made against the 2009-09-19 version and later of the Blob and Queue services". Are they wrong, or do I need to explicitly request a recent version?